# Orbeon Forms - Find current Document_id

Tags: orbeon

I want to have a text box have the current `document_id` displayed.  Is there an XPath expression to get that?

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath returns the current document id, the same that you see on the URL on the edit page you get by clicking on a form instance in the summary page.

```
xxforms:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/document
```

Note however that if you use this in a calculated expression, for new forms, the value won't show until a change was done in the form (e.g. users entered a value in a field).