# Orbeon get documentId

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I was interested in getting the documentId when submitting a form and link it to an user (i.e. by the email that is on a mandatory field of the form). The idea is to also call a webservice and send both fields to have this relationship. For now, I want to see this value in a field.

First of all, I have found that I can achieve this using `xxforms:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/document` but I have not success.

After this, I see [here](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1817) that now (I am using Orbeon 4.9) is changed to `fr:document-id()` but seems that I am still not able to see the document id in a simple field of the form. Bassically, something like:

```
<xf:action ev:event="xforms-submit">
   <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/somefield" value="fr:document-id()"/>
</xf:action>
```

Simple example created with Form Builder:

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
     xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
     xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
<xh:head>
    <xh:title>Send OrbeonID</xh:title>
    <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">

        <!-- Main instance -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <form>
                <section-1>
                    <control-1/>
                </section-1>
            </form>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Bindings -->
        <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
            <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
                <xf:bind id="control-1-bind" name="control-1" ref="control-1"/>
            </xf:bind>
        </xf:bind>

        <!-- Metadata -->
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>Biit</application-name>
                <form-name>SendOrbeonID</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en">Send OrbeonID</title>
                <description xml:lang="en"/>
                <singleton>false</singleton>
            </metadata>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Attachments -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <attachments>
                <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
            </attachments>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- All form resources -->
        <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="en">
                    <section-1>
                        <label>Untitled Section</label>
                    </section-1>
                    <control-1>
                        <label>Write something:</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <alert/>
                    </control-1>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Utility instances for services -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <request/>
        </xf:instance>

        <xf:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <response/>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Form is sent -->          
        <xf:action ev:event="xforms-submit">
            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/section-1/control-1" value="fr:document-id()"/>
        </xf:action>                

    </xf:model>
</xh:head>
<xh:body>
    <fr:view>
        <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                 xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
                 xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline">
            <fr:section id="section-1-control" bind="section-1-bind">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                <fr:grid>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:input id="control-1-control" bind="control-1-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-1/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-1/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xf:input>
                        </xh:td>
                        <xh:td/>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
    </fr:view>
</xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

Theorically, If I [fill up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173063/orbeon-forms-find-current-document-id) the input field and press the submit or save button, the field must be updated with the document id. But I am not able to see any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the way I have found to send the document Id is changing the behaviour of the buttons in Orbeon.

In the save as draft button:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save-draft.*.*">
   save
   then send("oxf.fr.detail.save-draft.success")
   then success-message("save-draft-success")
   recover error-message("database-error")
</property>
```

And define the `send` action to somewhere outside of Orbeon:

```
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.detail.new.accept-post.*.*" value="true" />
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.save-draft.success.uri.*.*" value="http://localhost:8080/get-id.jsp?document={xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/document}"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.save-draft.success.method.*.*" value="post"/>
```

The JSP page `get-id.jsp` now is executed each time that the user save the draft of the form, but the browser is not redirected to the JSP page.

Changing to use a webservice or other action must be easy.

Comment: And yes, confirmed that with a webservice also works.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that the document id is already sent as a URL parameter by default. The URL parameter name is `document`. See also the relevant [documentation](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Buttons-and-Processes#configuration).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. It is close of what I need. I going to test it and see if I can retrieve the document-id on this way and continue with my process.

Comment: Seems almost a solution. I can change the send action and send the document_id and the email to a URL. But my rest services are protected and this is the reason why I am trying to use standard webservices functionality of Orbeon. For now, I can send this information to a JSP page that handles the authorization and resend data, but maybe exist a better way to do this without intermediate jsp pages.

Comment: No, using JSP page is only a solution for "send" button, but If I use the "save" button you cannot continue working on your form. I am not sure if the documentation you write about "more powerful buttons" allows me to do it or continue with the original idea of launching a webservice.

Comment: I realize this has been a while but did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Only the explained in the other solution I proposed time ago.

Answer (score 0):

When you set your form builder controls calculated value to

```
xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/document
```

you can get the document id.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I have described in the accepted answered.